# Connection error while connecting to Oracle XE

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

This just started happening this morning, and I'm not sure what the cause is.  IT just installed some sort of Windows update but I'm not sure if this is related to the issue.  Basically, when I try to connect to Oracle I get a connection timeout error.  When I start to connect, I immediately see the following error message in the alert_xe.log file:

```
***********************************************************************

Fatal NI connect error 12560, connecting to:
 (LOCAL=NO)

  VERSION INFORMATION:
        TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
        Oracle Bequeath NT Protocol Adapter for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
        Windows NT TCP/IP NT Protocol Adapter for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
  Time: 28-JUL-2016 09:04:38
  Tracing not turned on.
Thu Jul 28 09:04:38 2016


***********************************************************************
  Tns error struct:

Fatal NI connect error 12560, connecting to:
 (LOCAL=NO)
    ns main err code: 12560

  VERSION INFORMATION:
        TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
        Oracle Bequeath NT Protocol Adapter for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
        Windows NT TCP/IP NT Protocol Adapter for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

  Time: 28-JUL-2016 09:04:38
TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  Tracing not turned on.
  Tns error struct:
    ns main err code: 12560

TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
    ns secondary err code: 0
    nt main err code: 0
    nt secondary err code: 0
    nt OS err code: 0
opiodr aborting process unknown ospid (9876) as a result of ORA-609
    ns secondary err code: 0
    nt main err code: 0
    nt secondary err code: 0
    nt OS err code: 0
opiodr aborting process unknown ospid (9316) as a result of ORA-609
```

I'm not really an Oracle expert, I'm a C# programmer and we just happen to use Oracle as our backend.  Any ideas on how to get me unstuck so I can continue my work?  Thanks!

Comment: My guess is an Oracle service is not running so I'd check there first. In other words, the update caused a reboot and you don't have Oracle set to autostart or you do and a service failed to start.

Comment: @topshot - Both instance and listener are running.  I can "ping" the listener and it's successful.  I've tried NET STOP and NET START to stop and start both, but the error persists.

Comment: From command prompt (may need to go to <home>\db_1\bin or similar directory if it's not in your path) you could type `lsnrctl` and once in the utility type `status` to see if it is servicing your instance. Might look at the listener logfile, too, which I seem to recall is in a logs directory (possibly under Network).

Answer (score 1):

> The ORA-609 error is thrown when a client connection of any kind failed to complete or aborted the connection process before the server process was completely spawned. Beginning with 10gR2, a default value for inbound connect timeout has been set at 60 seconds.  This is also triggered when a DB session is killed/aborted manually from the OS prompt.
>
> To remove a primary ORA-609 error, you should increase the values for INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT at both listener and server side sqlnet.ora file as a preventive measure. If the problem is due to connection timeouts, and increase in the following parameters should eliminate or reduce the occurrence of the ORA-609 error.
>
> - Sqlnet.ora: SQLNET.INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=180
> - Listener.ora: INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_listener_name=120

**Reference**
See: [ORA-609 opiodr aborting process unknown ospid tips](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_609_opiodr_aborting_process_unknown_ospid.htm) (Burleson Consulting)

Comment: Already tried this and it has no effect.  In the log, the error appears _immediately_ when trying to connect; it doesn't wait 60 seconds..